# Populate a checkboxlist with a list of values in VB.NET linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linq, webforms

I have a list of values for example:

```
Dim segments = New List(Of Segment) 
segments.Add(new Segmento() With {.Id= 1, .Name = "Segment 1" })
segments.Add(new Segmento() With {.Id = 2, .Name = "Segment 2" })
segments.Add(new Segmento() With {.Id = 3, .Name = "Segment 3" })

Dim selectedSegments = New List(Of  Integer) From {1,2}

CblSegments.DataSource = segments
CblSegments.DataValueField = "Id"
CblSegments.DataTextField = "Name"
CblSegments.DataBind()
```

Now, i have to select items in the CblSegments checklist with selectedSegments values with linq in Vb .net.

Anyone can help?
Thanks.

Comment: You want to select the items which have `Id` equal to one of the items in `selectedSegments` ?

Comment: Yes @dubonzi, with linq/lambda. With for each loop inside another it's working, but it's too ugly.

Comment: Linq is for querying not for performing an action (such as marking items as selected). Go with a for loop.

Comment: I can query items from checkboxlist compare with selected items list and select them. Or not?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 2 `For Each` loops to accomplish this, you can just do:

```
Dim CblSegments As New CheckBoxList

Dim segments = New List(Of Segmento)
segments.Add(New Segmento() With {.Id = 1, .Name = "Segment 1"})
segments.Add(New Segmento() With {.Id = 2, .Name = "Segment 2"})
segments.Add(New Segmento() With {.Id = 3, .Name = "Segment 3"})

Dim selectedSegments = New List(Of Integer) From {1, 2}    
CblSegments.DataSource = segments
CblSegments.DataValueField = "Id"
CblSegments.DataTextField = "Name"
CblSegments.DataBind()

For Each cblItem As ListItem In CblSegments.Items
    If selectedSegments.Contains(cblItem.Value) Then
        cblItem.Selected = True
    End If
Next
```

Comment: this way i can get what was selected in the checkboxlist.

Comment: I need select checked items from a list of values.

Comment: I saw this for c#, but i couldn't get working in vb.net.

Comment: Ah so I misunderstood your question.. Ill edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For C#:

```
private class servicetimeofday
{
public int servicetimeofdayid { get; set; }
public int serviceid { get; set; }
public int timeofdayid { get; set; }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
List<servicetimeofday> servicetimesofday = new List<servicetimeofday>
{
new servicetimeofday() { servicetimeofdayid = 1, serviceid = 1, timeofdayid = 1 },
new servicetimeofday() { servicetimeofdayid = 2, serviceid = 1, timeofdayid = 2 },
new servicetimeofday() { servicetimeofdayid = 3, serviceid = 2, timeofdayid = 1 },
new servicetimeofday() { servicetimeofdayid = 4, serviceid = 2, timeofdayid = 3 }
};

var itemstocheck = from s in servicetimesofday
where s.serviceid == 2
select s.servicetimeofdayid;

(from i in CheckBoxList2.Items.Cast<ListItem>() 
where itemstocheck.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(i.Value))
select i).ToList().ForEach(i => i.Selected = true);
}
```